Facebook site got added to fake business manager created by WhatsApp Business
My Facebook site got randomly added to non-existent business manager with the same name as the site. It happened when I added WhatsApp Business number to the site through Facebook settings. Random notification about this appeared and I can't move my site back to my real business manager. Removing the number didn't do anything either. The site is now managed by an inaccessible business manager that apparently has 0 managers, according to support.
Does anyone have any idea as to how to solve this issue? Definitely not Facebook's support. They... want me to send proof that I am the owner of the fake business manager, even though it never "existed" and I never asked for it. They mention credit card purchases related to the business manager as an example, which I can't provide for obvious reasons - no such actions were done there by me.
This is just crazy, they are like robots, 0 logical thinking and understanding that it's a clear service integration bug. And on WhatsApp Business I only get answers from literal robots - the most obvious AI ever, poorly written one too, not able to understand my question at all.
Or did anyone encounter such a problem at least? I think this question has the same issue How to find out who manages the Facebook Business Manager but it's not solved or even identified too well.
I don't mind getting rid of the business manager completely if such option existed, as long as the site is left in tact all solutions are fine.
